# Level-Wise Sorting of Series in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, pandas, series

I have a dataframe called mydf

```
mydf
```

[image]

I performed below operation and it is then converted into a series.

```
mydf.groupby([mydf.type,mydf.name]).size()
```

Now I have a series with two levels of type i.e. actor and actress.

```
    type      name               
    actor    'Big' Ben Moroz        1
             'Ducky' Louie          3
             'Fast' Eddie Mahler    1
             'King Kong' Kashey     1
             'Muddy' Berry          1

    actress   Zedra Conde           3
              Zena Marshall         1
              Zinaida Morskaya      1
              Zoe Holland           1
              Zoia Karabanova       2
```

Now I want my result to be sorted in descending order in the **level** actor and if actor **"value"** (given in third unnamed say column) is same then the sorting must be done by **"name"** and then same pattern must be followed when sorting is done in other **level** called actress

```
type      name               
actor    'Ducky' Louie          3
         'Big' Ben Moroz        1
         'Fast' Eddie Mahler    1
         'King Kong' Kashey     1
         'Muddy' Berry          1

actress   Zedra Conde           3
          Zoia Karabanova       2
          Zena Marshall         1
          Zinaida Morskaya      1
          Zoe Holland           1
```

Note:- Please avoid looping.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately everything I came up with requires double grouping/sorting. Suppose we have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

d = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['actor']*5+['actress']*5,  
                  'name' : [random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c']) for i in range(10)]})
d


    name    type
0   c   actor
1   c   actor
2   a   actor
3   b   actor
4   a   actor
5   c   actress
6   c   actress
7   c   actress
8   a   actress
9   a   actress


d.groupby([d.type,d.name]).size()

type     name
actor    a       2
         b       1
         c       2
actress  a       2
         c       3
dtype: int64
```

Approach 1:

```
d.groupby([d.type,d.name]).size().groupby(level=[0]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))

type     type     name
actor    actor    c       2
                  a       2
                  b       1
actress  actress  c       3
                  a       2
dtype: int64
```

Approach 2:

```
d1 = d.groupby([d.type,d.name]).size()
d2 = d1.reset_index()
d2.columns = ['type', 'actress', 'sz']
d2.sort_values(by = ['type',  'sz', 'actress'], ascending = [True, False, True])

    type    actress sz
0   actor   a   2
2   actor   c   2
1   actor   b   1
4   actress c   3
3   actress a   2
```